# static configure of dynamic parameters

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe is a noob question but,
parameters that are "dynamically" reconfigurable can be static too?
If I put the parameter value inside the launch file does it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200966/static-configure-of-dynamic-parameters/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

:-)

They can be initialized using a launch file, like

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0